# FTP Batch Scripts in Windows not working

Tags: ftp, batch-file, dos, ftp-client

I try to download a set of files from an FTP. I use the following command for that.

```
ftp  -v -s:DownloadCommand.txt ftp.SampleFTP.com>>%log%
```

This particular code works when executed in the development machine, but when executed in production, it does't work. I have nothing logged into my log file. No error is getting thrown.

Can someone help.? Thanks.

Additional Info. the Downloadcommand.txt has the following

```
<username>
<password>
binary
cd <FolderName>
lcd <LocalPath>
prompt
mget <FileName>
quit
```

Comment: That usually means that the ftp command is prompting for something.  What commands are inside the `DownloadCommand.txt`?  One scenario that I can think about is if just the username is specified and the password is being pulled from the system credentials storage.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann: I have included the Downloadcommand.txt content in the question.

Comment: Is this in a Windows environment?  If so check the encoding method of the DownloadCommand.txt file.  -s will read plain text ASCII only.  UTF or Unicode files with those extra two bytes at the beginning will stump ftp.

Comment: How can I make it to ask the user for the password (the user should type the password manually)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was DownloadCommand.txt was not accessible by the .bat file, though they were on the same folder. I solved the problem, by using PUSHD "path of the DownloadCommand.txt" before calling the FTP.